# ViewDidLoad calling again after segue performed

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am experiencing an unusual error when segueing back to my main view controller.

When a user registers within the app it creates a unique CloudKit record. Once the save operation is completed, an NSNotification is broadcast from the cloudKit saveRecord closure which displays an alert to the user. When the alert is accepted a segue to a new viewController is performed.

When segueing back to the main view controller it runs viewDidLoad & viewDidAppear again, causing various functions to stop working. I have found that the original instance of my main view controller is still in memory and can be accessed.

I believe the issue could have something to do with threading and the performForSegue being called off of the main thread, although I'm using GCD and this shouldn't be the case.

Here is my code:

Save function:

```
func saveRecord(newUser: CKRecord) {

database.saveRecord(newUser) { record, error in

  if error != nil {

    print(error)
    Properties.registrationError = error

  } else {

    Properties.registrationSuccess = record
    print(record)
  }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Key.Registration, object: self)
 }
}
```

When the saveRecord notification is received:

```
func registrationComplete() {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

  self.pleaseWait.alpha = 0
  self.stopIndicator()
  print("stop indicator")

  if Properties.registrationError != nil {

    self.displayAlert("Registration Failed", error: "\(Properties.registrationError!.localizedDescription)", performAction: .None)

  } else {

    self.displayAlert("Registration Completed", error: "Press OK to begin induction", performAction: .BeginInduction)
  }
 }
}
```

When OK is pressed:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("beginInduction", sender: self)
```

For testing I am segueing straight back to the main controller when the new view appears. At this point the original controller's viewDidLoad is run again. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` it will load a new view controller associated with "beginInduction" identifier and not go back to the existing instance which you may have created with a pervious `performSegueWithIdentifier`. What you have to do is to use an unwind segue.

More details are in this link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Alternatively you can use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` or `popToViewController` or `popViewController` or `dismissViewController` methods to go back to the pervious view controllers

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Is there one method you would prefer or recommend as best practice over the others?

Comment: It depends on how you view controller hierarchy is built. If you are using navigation controller and your main controller is the root view controller then you can use `popToRootViewController`. Otherwise you can use `dismissViewController` if the view controller on top of your main controller is presented as modal view controller

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm not using a navigation controller and I don't need to go to the main controller until three other controllers have been accessed. I've just followed your instructions and unwinding works perfectly. Cheers :)